# Populate a variable with values using a loop and than retrieve a specific "moment" of that variable

Tags: javascript, loops, phaser-framework

Sorry for the somewhat vague title. I searched the web and stackoverflow but I'm a bit (more than a bit actually) confused.

Let me explain:
I'm using javascript and Phaser framework. I'm creating a single variable with a sprite, but with a for loop I dynamically change the texture and give it custom values. Like so:

```
    for (var x = 0; x < some value; x++) {

         this.myVar = this.game.add.sprite(this.world.width * .5, 480, 'gui_images', '');

          this.myVar.customParams = {
               clicked: false,
               labelColor: 'labelBlue_small',
               somethingArray: this.arraySomething[x],
               somethingArrayPosition: x
             };
}
```

So far I only needed to access or compare against a given value. So I would use a function and do something like:

```
myComparingFunction: function(item) {
    if(item.customParams.clicked){
        //do something
    }
}
```

No problems so far.

--- PROBLEM STARTS HERE ---

if I do a console.log() to myVar and check its customParams I will get the last value of the loop. (i.e. if the loop runs from 0 < 5, I will get 4 from `console.log(myVar.customParams.somethingArrayPosition)`)

What I want to do and is confusing me is: I want to create a temporary variable that will represent, for example, position 2 of myVar.customParams.somethingArrayPosition...

something like:

```
var temp = myVar.customParams.somethingArrayPosition[2]...
```

so I can say `temp.visible = false;` and make it disappear... Right now I only get the last sprite disappearing, or get the value and not a way to say that value refers to that sprite, hide it!

Cheers and sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm really puzzled at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the easiest solution is to create your array as a property of your `Phaser.Game` instance, and then add your sprites to it.

I've [created a JSFiddle that showcases this](https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/hcmfu992/), but an example of the relevant code is:

```
create: function() { 
    this.spriteCollection = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        this.ball = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, 5 + 30 * x, 'ball');
      this.ball.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0);
      this.spriteCollection.push(this.ball);
    }
    // Will return all three sprites, which you can go through and see have the correct position.
    console.log(this.spriteCollection);
    // As shown here.
    console.log(this.spriteCollection[0].position);
    // Uncomment to see this in action.
    this.spriteCollection[1].visible = false;
},
```

You can still continue to add a `customParams` to each sprite you add, but don't rely on the individual sprites array property; if you `console.log` I believe you'll see it's getting overwritten on each loop, since `this.myVar = this.game.add.sprite(this.world.width * .5, 480, 'gui_images', '');` is resetting `this.myVar`.

Comment: Thank you, James! This and groups is something that I have to get used to... Yes, I tend to rely on individual sprites properties and yes, the sprite itself is overwritten but I can still call and see individual properties and use them. E.g. I have an apple tree with 6 apples. They are all the same sprite, created like my code above. Each has a value that is x, so it increments. on a function, if I do something like `invisble: function (item){ if(item.customParams.value == 2){ item.visible = false;}}` it will work... but this is a better solution for most of the times! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with Phaser. :)